# Android: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I have a project in which, when a particular activity is called from an explicit intent, i have a crash followed by this type of error. The fact that i don't understand is how on devices with android 4.0 or higher everything works fine. I have tried to run the application on android 2.2 and android 2.3 and i have the crash with this error.
The activity that causes the crash doesn't require any type of external jars, except for the android-support-v4 one. I have tried to think some several solutions, for example the compatibility of fragment api (but there is the support-v4 for this, right?), but i haven't found anything that can help me.
Do you have some suugestions for my problem?
Thanks in advance!

E/dalvikvm(278): Could not find class 'com.example.MainActivity', referenced from method com.example.SplashActivity$1.handleMessage

E/AndroidRuntime(278):         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.MainActivity

E/AndroidRuntime(278):         at com.example.SplashActivity$1.handleMessage(SplashActivity.java:53)

E/AndroidRuntime(278):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(278):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

E/AndroidRuntime(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

E/AndroidRuntime(278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

E/AndroidRuntime(278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

E/AndroidRuntime(278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

E/AndroidRuntime(278):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnCloseListener;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MenuFragment.OnListSelectedListener,DetailsFragment.OnSaveListener, OnCloseListener, OnQueryTextListener, android.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener, OnFocusChangeListener, OnMenuItemClickListener,OnClickListener,TextWatcher{
```

Comment: Can you give more details, obviously you have a requirements missmatch as something is being casted as the android 4 version rather than the supported version.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code or the exact error message, I can't tell you exactly what's going on.  It does sounds like you are using the system Fragment class instead of the support library Fragment.

You can check your imports.

It should look like this.

`import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

if it looks like this

`import android.app.FragmentActivity;`

`import android.app.Fragment;`

Then you are using the system versions which are unavailable on older android versions.

Comment: I have controlled the imports and i used the support.v4 library as you have posted.

Comment: is it working now?  if not, what class is it not able to find?

Comment: no :(, i've added the error on the question. The splash activity calls main activity with an explicit intent

Comment: ok, it can't find your com.example.MainActivity class. I'm assuming this exists and is in the correct place.  What specific class does your MainActivity class extend?  Can you post that code too?

Comment: MainActivity extends fragmentactivity. That class is so long. What part of the code do you need?

Comment: Interesting, it certainly sounds like you are importing the wrong fragment activity.  Let's go from the top of the file, include package, all your imports and the public class MainActivity extends line.

Comment: i have the import that you have suggested. Are you looking for some certain imports in particular?

Comment: inserted what you have requested.

Comment: It is likely the import android.app.ActionBar; that is messing you up.  You can't use ActionBar on GingerBread.  If you need to mess with the actionbar, consider switching to ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Can ActionBar's import give that type of error? Cause i've tried to apply ActionBarSherlock but i still have NoClassDefFound Error on MainActivity

Comment: If you reference it.  Try temporarily changing the sdk you are compiling against to Gingerbread.  You should get errors.

Comment: Yes, i got errors: it wasn't the action bar, but the searchview's listener, so i solved importing the right one from actionbarsherlock. Thanks for your help!!